# Filtrar Máximo y Mínimo DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Soy nuevo en python y todo lo que tenga que ver con programación. Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un DataFrame de la siguiente forma:

---

```
Oficina     Año       Inversión

Arte        2004        17.204
Arte        2005        16.242
Arte        2010        19.858
Arte        2016        20.367
Biotec      2005        18.995
Biotec      2010        16.398
Biotec      2011        16.763
Biotec      2015        21.454
Periodismo  2004        15.918
Periodismo  2010        18.538
Periodismo  2016        23.326
Sociales    2005        21.832
Sociales    2006        22.002
Sociales    2011        26.833
Veterin     2009        22.599
```

---

Estoy tratando de filtrarlo con pandas buscando generar un nuevo DataFrame con el primer y último año de inversión para cada una de las oficinas

traté de usar una expresión como la siguiente:

```
minimos =  df.loc[df["Año"].idxmin()]
maximos =  df.loc[df["Año"].idxmax()]
```

---

Pero me entrega el valor solo de un índice, no tengo idea de como obtener primer y último año de cada oficina y menos cómo filtrar los datos para que queden sólo esas filas, agrupadas por oficina.

Estoy usando Python 3.7.

Les ruego su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que haces es obtener el año mínimo o máximo de la columna y luego aplicar un filtro boleano sobre el DataFrame seleccionado aquellas filas que tiene como año el valor mínimo o máximo de toda la columna.

Si lo he entendido bien, debes usar `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, agrupar por `Oficina` y aplicar `min` y `max` a la columna `Año`. La pista de que debemos agrupar es:

> "primer y último año de inversión **para cada una** de las oficinas".

Solo para reproducir el ejemplo:

```
import io

import pandas as pd


data = io.StringIO("""
Oficina     Año      Inversión
Arte        2004        17.204
Arte        2005        16.242
Arte        2010        19.858
Arte        2016        20.367
Biotec      2005        18.995
Biotec      2010        16.398
Biotec      2011        16.763
Biotec      2015        21.454
Periodismo  2004        15.918
Periodismo  2010        18.538
Periodismo  2016        23.326
Sociales    2005        21.832
Sociales    2006        22.002
Sociales    2011        26.833
Veterin     2009        22.599
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+",  engine="python")
```

---

```
res = df.groupby("Oficina")["Año"].agg(Año_inicial="min", Año_final="max")
```

> ```
> >>> res
>             Año_inicial  Año_final
> Oficina                           
> Arte               2004       2016
> Biotec             2005       2015
> Periodismo         2004       2016
> Sociales           2005       2011
> Veterin            2009       2009
> ```

Si quieres también la inversión de cada año, la idea sería la misma, agrupar:

```
idxs = df.groupby(["Oficina"])["Año"].agg(["idxmin", "idxmax"])
maximos = df.loc[idxs["idxmax"]]
minimos = df.loc[idxs["idxmin"]]
```

> ```
> >>> maximos
>        Oficina   Año  Inversión
> 3         Arte  2016     20.367
> 7       Biotec  2015     21.454
> 10  Periodismo  2016     23.326
> 13    Sociales  2011     26.833
> 14     Veterin  2009     22.599
>
> >>> minimos
>        Oficina   Año  Inversión
> 0         Arte  2004     17.204
> 4       Biotec  2005     18.995
> 8   Periodismo  2004     15.918
> 11    Sociales  2005     21.832
> 14     Veterin  2009     22.599
> ```

Si quieres un único DataFrame, simpre puedes hacer un merge por ejemplo:

```
idxs = df.groupby(["Oficina"])["Año"].agg(["idxmin", "idxmax"])
res = pd.merge(
    left=df.loc[idxs["idxmin"]],
    right=df.loc[idxs["idxmax"]],
    on="Oficina",
    how="outer",
    suffixes=('_inicial', '_final')
)
```

> ```
> >>> res
>
>       Oficina  Año_inicial  Inversión_inicial  Año_final  Inversión_final
> 0        Arte         2004             17.204       2016           20.367
> 1      Biotec         2005             18.995       2015           21.454
> 2  Periodismo         2004             15.918       2016           23.326
> 3    Sociales         2005             21.832       2011           26.833
> 4     Veterin         2009             22.599       2009           22.599
> ```

Se podría hacer todo de una vez con `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.transform`, pero a día de hoy y desde hace bastante... hay un bug que impide usar `transform` con varias columnas y/o funciones simultáneamente.

Comment: Thanks a lot FJSevilla, i'll test this right now (i need some time to assimilate data  LOL). In some ways python is like chinese for me still.

Comment: Hola John, primero,bienvenido a [es.so]. No estaba muy seguro de la salida final que buscabas, si quieres algo diferente comenta. Si tienes cualquier duda acerca de algo en la respuesta que te "suene a chino" :) tampoco dudes en preguntar, a veces se obvian cosas al responder que no son para nada obvias para alguien que empieza con la herramienta de turno. Saludos.

Comment: Perdón, me confundí de foro y respondí en un idioma que no corresponde.

La salida buscada sería algo así como lo que escribiste en el segundo bloque, hasta ahora lo modifiqué con los nombres originales (tenía que usarlo sobre un archivo de una url) y anduvo bien.

Muchísimas gracias , eres muy amable !!! :)